# Where will the result will be stored? after executing PMD

Tags: command-prompt, pmd

I am using PMD to do code-review for my application.
I am able to do the review, but I don't have a clue where the report will be stored. I am using this cmd:

```
"C:\PMD test\Source>java -jar pmd-4.2.5/lib/pmd-4.2.5.jar JavaSource\com\ex\app html basic"
```

in the command prompt.

It is displaying the entire result in the command window.

Is there any way to store the result as an HTML file or any other file type? If it is the case, where will it be stored? Do we need to configure anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: how to write cmd output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438065/windows-batch-how-to-write-cmd-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out a way to re-direct the console output to another text file. That solves the problem. i am just renaming the extension txt to html.

So actual command should be "**C:\PMD test\Source>java -jar pmd-4.2.5/lib/pmd-4.2.5.jar JavaSource\com\ex\app html basic *>result.txt***"

">result.txt" actually redirects the console output to result.txt file