# Windows batch: how to write cmd output to a file?

Tags: batch-file, logging, stderr

I need to print into a text file the lines that appear in the cmd window when the batch is running. For instance, I have the following batch script:

```
copy D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt
```

When I launch the batch file, the cmd window displays the following lines (sorry my Windows is in french):

```
D:\>copy D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt
    1 fichier(s) copié(s)
```

I would like to automatically write these 2 lines in a text file in order to check the execution of more complex batch files and to track errors.

Comment: Use [output redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), for example: `call mybatchfile.bat >>logfile.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect the output of a batch command into a file `log.txt`:

```
D:\>copy D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt >log.txt
```

Append the output to the file

```
copy D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt >>log.txt
```

Note that you might want to suppress the confirmation whether or not to overwrite the target file. Use the `/Y` option to do so (but be aware of the risks):

```
copy /Y D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt >>log.txt
```

Also note that the issued command line is not part of the output. Write it using the `echo` command:

```
echo copy /Y D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt >>log.txt
copy /Y D:\aaa.txt D:\bbb.txt >>log.txt
```

Comment: Many thanks @collapsar! Your last two lines did help me perfectly.